# Lift Framework BindHelpers.attr Question (or better practice?)

Tags: xml, xhtml, scala, bind, lift

My problem is extracting xhtml attributes to generate absolute links,
since they need to be different on testing and production
environment.
I would like to use a "global snippet" that binds all "src" and "href"
attributes to "localhost:8080" or "www.mydomain.com" depending on a
conf value.

This is how the template looks like:

```
<lift:Global>
  <html><body><a G:href="/somelink">some text</a></body></html>
</lift:Global>
```

And this is the Global.render method:

```
bind("G",template,
  AttrBindParam("href",Conf.localhost
    +BindHelpers.attr("G","href").map(_.toString).getOrElse("none") ,"href")
)
```

But in the rendered page all I see is ... href="confValueNone".

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a better way to configure for different environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use AttributeSnippets now. They are a bit heavier on the template side, but result in cleaner snippets.

snippet:

```
import xml.{UnprefixedAttribute, MetaData}

...

def src(in:MetaData):MetaData = {
  new UnprefixedAttribute("src",Conf.localhost+in.value.toString,scala.xml.Null)
}

def href(in:MetaData):MetaData = {
  val out = new UnprefixedAttribute("href",Conf.localhost+in.value.toString,scala.xml.Null)
  out
}
```

template:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" lift:Global.src="/inc/showdown.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" lift:Global.href="/inc/style.css" />
...
```